# Translating words on custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate on my project. I can translate words on views by using

But having trouble with my filter:

```
angular.module('MyModule')
   .filter('weekdays', function () {
        return function (weekday_nums) {
           var weekday_arr = weekday_nums.split("");

  var _weekday_arr = weekday_arr.map(function (day) {
    day = parseInt(day);
    if (isNaN(day)) return;
    if (day === 1) day = "Pzts";
    if (day === 2) day = "Salı";
    if (day === 3) day = "Çar";
    if (day === 4) day = "Per";
    if (day === 5) day = "Cuma";
    if (day === 6) day = "Cmts";
    if (day === 7) day = "Paz";

    return day;
  });

  return _weekday_arr.join(" ");
};
});
```

I had translations on my en.json file:

```
   "shortdays": {
"MONDAY": "Mon",
"TUESDAY": "Tue",
"WEDNESDAY": "Wed",
"THURSDAY": "Thu",
"FRIDAY": "Fri",
"SATURDAY": "Sat",
"SUNDAY": "Sun",
"EVERYDAY": "Everyday",
"STARTAT": "Start At",
"ENDAT": "End At"
```

},

How can i translate dynamically those days?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Which part isn't working? I have a couple of ideas but I'd need some guidance to know exactly which part is broken.

Comment: That filter <p>{{sche.weekdays | weekdays}}</p> gives me something like that: "ptesi salı çar cuma" 
I need to to translate it to other languages. So when english selected:
"mon tue wed fri"

Comment: So the filter is being passed a plain string with spaces and you want the filter to display a plain string with spaces in the new language?

Comment: @bobbyz that's right sir.

Comment: K, I'll play around and see what I come up with. But just to be sure, for my test I could use `$scope.sche.weekdays = "ptesi salı çar cuma"`?

Comment: @bobbyz yes you could.

Comment: And how is the `en.json` file being used? Right now I have it working with hard-coded values, which I'll submit in an answer for you to see, and then I'll update it to reflect however `en.json` is supposed to be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't yet reflect how `en.json` is being used because I'm unfamiliar with angular-translate (which I'll look up now to improve this answer).

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.sche = {
            weekdays: "Pzts Salı Çar Cuma"
        };
    }])
    .filter('weekdays', function () {
        return function (weekdays) {
            var weekdayArr = weekdays.split(" ");
            var englishWeekdays = weekdayArr.map(function (day) {
                if (day === "Pzts") return "Mon";
                if (day === "Salı") return "Tues";
                if (day === "Çar") return "Wed";
                if (day === "Per") return "Thurs";
                if (day === "Cuma") return "Fri";
                if (day === "Cmts") return "Sat";
                if (day === "Paz") return "Sun";
            });

            console.log(englishWeekdays);
            return englishWeekdays.join(" ");
        };
    });
```